# If statement in python function

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have some errors for my data to calculate. The errors change at a certain point and there must be a slight adjustment in the function for that.
So I need something like this:

```
import numpy as np

U1=np.array([0.1,0.5,1,2])

def UErr(U):
    if U>0.68:
        return 0.003*U+0.01
    else:
        return 0.003*U+0.001

U1Err=UErr(U1)
```

This obviously doesn't work, because U>0.68 can't be true, since it is an array.
I want to do that (in words):
It should return an array with following values:

```
U1Err=([0.0013,0.0025,0.013,0.016])
```

I know, it is a very basic question and since I am just learning python on the side for some (light) data analysis, I am missing quite a lot of th basics.

Would be grateful if anyone could help me. :)

Comment: Is this supposed to return the entire array (or a `list` in Python) with the corrected values?

Comment: you have iterate through the loop.

Comment: "can't be true, since it is an array" why don't you then try to make it work yourself? Additionally what is "x"?

Comment: Is `U` a list containing only one elements?

Comment: I have two words for you: list comprehension.

Comment: `arrayName[x]` to access a specific element in your array

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list as input, you need to loop over or apply a function over it

```
def UErr(U):
    return map(lambda u: 0.003*u+0.01 if u > 0.68 else 0.003*u+0.001,  U)
```

Comment: Okay, I've checked again. This doesn't really work. Because in U there are elements bigger than 0.68 it returns the higher value (0.003*u+0.01) for all elements and not only the ones which are bigger than 0.68...  Let's assume    U=np.array([2,1,0.5,0.1]) then it should return a value of 0.16 for the first and 0.0013 for the last element. With your code I get 0.0103 for the last. :/

Comment: I'm not sure why you need Numpy, but check answer again

Answer (score 0):

Can also do this way:

```
def UErr(U):
    if any(i > 0.68 for i in U):
        return map(lambda x:0.003*x+0.01,U)
    else:
        return map(lambda x:0.003*x+0.001,U)
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to run a loop to go over each element of the list or array. If you want to get all the elements of the whole array you can return the list until the end.

```
def UErr(U):
    for element in range(0,len(U)):
        if U[element] > 0.68:
            U[element]= 0.003*U+0.01
        else:
            U[element] = 0.003*U+0.01
    return U
```

Comment: `element` is a value from the list, not an index. `U[element]` will fail unless `U` contains consecutive integers starting from 0.

Comment: that is true, it needs to go over the range of the list not the element itself. made the correction :)